# Angular 7 Component Observable Named vs Anonymous function

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, observable, angular7

I have created an Angular 7 component that has an observable from an angular service. I am using it to bind data from a remote service to a list on one of my pages. It works pretty good. However, one thing I noticed is in the subscribe asynchronous callback if I use a named function instead of an anonymous function the data does not bind to the list on my page.

Here is an example of the current anonymous callback which works

```
public constructor(private vendorApiService: VendorApiService,
    private eventMessagingService: EventMessagingService) {

    this.vendorApiService.getVendors().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this._vendor = data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Vendor>(this._vendor);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      });
    this._displayedColumns = ['id', 'code', 'name', 'edit'];
}
```

I would like to convert it to this. However, this does not work:

```
public constructor(private vendorApiService: VendorApiService,
  private eventMessagingService: EventMessagingService) {

    this.vendorApiService.getVendors().subscribe(
      this.setup_vendor_list);
    this._displayedColumns = ['id', 'code', 'name', 'edit'];
}

private setup_vendor_list(data) {
  this._vendor = data;
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Vendor>(this._vendor);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Based on what I know about Javascript this should work. However, since this is typescript, there may be some special condition I am not aware of that impacts the way named and anonymous callbacks are handled.

If you can explain the difference, please do so.

Comment: what are you getting in the second scenario ?

Comment: Add a `console.log` and try to log `this` in your function. Arrow functions don't change the value of `this`, but named functions do. It's probably the reason why it won't work. You can, however, pass an arrow function that calls your function instead, as in `(data) => setup_vendor_list(data)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about TypeScript, it's still pure JavaScript issue. Passing `this.setup_vendor_list` as a an argument is the same as passing

```
function (...args) { return this.setup_vendor_list(...args) },
```

which is *not* the same as

```
(...args) => this.setup_vendor_list(...args),
```

which you seem to believe.

It's also not about named vs anonymous functions: notice how both of my examples are anonymous. However, only one is an *arrow function*.

The difference which affects you is the way `this` is resolved inside these functions, which you can read more about in [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/2131286).

---

Two quickest workarounds:

```
subscribe(this.setup_vendor_list.bind(this))
subscribe(data => this._setup_vendor_list(data))
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct about "this". I should have realized this. I sometimes forget about "this" context.  Thanks for the assist.